Does an Incorporeal Creature add 1.5 x Dexterity to damage when wielding a two-handed weapon?
When a creature becomes incorporeal they use Dexterity in place of Strength for attacks, I take that to assume to-hit and damage. Does it function in all the same ways Strength does including adding 1.5x damage with two-handed weapons?


It has no Strength score, so its Dexterity modifier applies to its melee attacks, ranged attacks, and CMB.

(Incorporeal universal monster ability)
This could be clearer—“attack rolls” rather than “attacks”—but my reading, and the consensus on the internet, is that this does in fact only apply to attack rolls, and thus not to damage rolls. So no, an incorporeal does not add 1½×Dexterity to their damage rolls—they don’t add any Dexterity to their damage rolls (unless they’re also an unchained rogue or something).
If this ability did specify damage rolls, then yes, it would (almost certainly) be multiplied by 1½× for a weapon wielded two-handed. Paizo has an FAQ about this for the unchained rogue, so as long as the hypothetical ability works the same way, it would also be multiplied. But incorporeal creatures don’t have that ability.
